# Eclipse Hono deployment on AWS k8s

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-vpc, eclipse-hono

I am trying to deploy the Eclipse Hono version 1.0 on AWS k8s cluster. Below are the services after deployment (strange external IPs).

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# kubectl get service -n hono

service/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx                   LoadBalancer   100.67.94.188    a25d01250eb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-2016210601.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com   5672:32672/TCP,5671:32671/TCP     4h46m
service/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-headless          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
service/hono-adapter-http-vertx                   LoadBalancer   100.70.64.248    a25dc920deb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-730471375.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com    8080:30080/TCP,8443:30443/TCP     4h46m
service/hono-adapter-http-vertx-headless          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
service/hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx                   LoadBalancer   100.68.3.95      a25ed2e15eb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-1002962271.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com   1883:31883/TCP,8883:30883/TCP     4h46m
service/hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx-headless          ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
service/hono-artemis                              ClusterIP      100.70.153.152   <none>                                                                    5671/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-dispatch-router                      ClusterIP      100.64.140.172   <none>                                                                    5673/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-dispatch-router-ext                  LoadBalancer   100.70.95.31     a25b7cb1ceb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-370392986.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com    15671:30671/TCP,15672:30672/TCP   4h46m
service/hono-grafana                              ClusterIP      100.67.252.68    <none>                                                                    3000/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-prometheus-server                    ClusterIP      100.65.95.65     <none>                                                                    9090/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-service-auth                         ClusterIP      100.66.3.21      <none>                                                                    5671/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-service-auth-headless                ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
service/hono-service-device-connection-headless   ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
service/hono-service-device-registry              ClusterIP      100.67.196.156   <none>                                                                    5671/TCP                          4h46m
service/hono-service-device-registry-ext          LoadBalancer   100.65.10.48     a2604531feb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-643429943.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com    28080:31080/TCP,28443:31443/TCP   4h46m
service/hono-service-device-registry-headless     ClusterIP      None             <none>                                                                    <none>                            4h46m
```

List of pods:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# kubectl get pods -n hono

pod/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc-555s9   0/1     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-adapter-http-vertx-54b7848749-fnjk5   0/1     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx-76b546bf76-9fw9w   0/1     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-artemis-5fdb775c46-pzdfz              1/1     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-dispatch-router-78ccc6579c-qk8pw      1/1     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-grafana-8d5d6476f-wnw96               2/2     Running             0          4h46m
pod/hono-grafana-test                          0/1     Error               0          4h46m
pod/hono-prometheus-server-5676c8f974-bvmw8    0/2     ContainerCreating   0          4h46m
pod/hono-service-auth-c669986d-78c4q           1/1     Running             0          4h46m
```

Pods are running partially. Describing a failed pod (e.g., AMQP), the result is as follows:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# kubectl -n hono describe pod hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc-555s9

Name:           hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc-555s9
Namespace:      hono
Priority:       0
Node:           ip-172-20-60-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal/172.20.60.72
Start Time:     Thu, 10 Oct 2019 08:15:40 +0000
Labels:         app.kubernetes.io/component=adapter-amqp-vertx
                app.kubernetes.io/instance=hono
                app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Tiller
                app.kubernetes.io/name=eclipse-hono
                app.kubernetes.io/version=1.0-M7
                helm.sh/chart=eclipse-hono-1.0-M7
                pod-template-hash=6888d8fffc
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Running
IP:             100.96.1.7
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc
Containers:
  eclipse-hono-adapter-amqp-vertx:
    Container ID:   docker://33641eef4c25d50bc54947d396bc4c6e457a86369a51acaa0befcf2ee0307508
    Image:          index.docker.io/eclipse/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx:1.0-M7
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://eclipse/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx@sha256:982d2ac2824eb95b915fc53756a6b05fd6939473af7bf39cbf1351127adf6b04
    Ports:          8088/TCP, 5671/TCP, 5672/TCP
    Host Ports:     0/TCP, 0/TCP, 0/TCP
    State:          Running
      Started:      Thu, 10 Oct 2019 08:16:06 +0000
    Ready:          False
    Restart Count:  0
    Limits:
      memory:  256Mi
    Requests:
      memory:   256Mi
    Liveness:   http-get https://:8088/liveness delay=180s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Readiness:  http-get https://:8088/readiness delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3
    Environment:
      SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION:  file:///etc/hono/
      SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE:  dev
      LOGGING_CONFIG:          classpath:logback-spring.xml
      _JAVA_OPTIONS:           -XX:MinRAMPercentage=80 -XX:MaxRAMPercentage=80
      KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE:    hono (v1:metadata.namespace)
      JAEGER_SERVICE_NAME:     hono-adapter-amqp-vertx
    Mounts:
      /etc/hono from conf (ro)
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-phj96 (ro)
Conditions:
  Type              Status
  Initialized       True
  Ready             False
  ContainersReady   False
  PodScheduled      True
Volumes:
  conf:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-conf
    Optional:    false
  default-token-phj96:
    Type:        Secret (a volume populated by a Secret)
    SecretName:  default-token-phj96
    Optional:    false
QoS Class:       Burstable
Node-Selectors:  <none>
Tolerations:     node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute for 300s
                 node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason     Age                       From                                                 Message
  ----     ------     ----                      ----                                                 -------
  Warning  Unhealthy  4m34s (x1677 over 4h43m)  kubelet, ip-172-20-60-72.eu-west-3.compute.internal  Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503
```

A failed pod logs (pod/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc-555s9):

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# kubectl -n hono logs hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-6888d8fffc-njmvr

13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - can't connect to AMQP 1.0 container [amqps://hono-service-device-registry:5671]: Connection refused: hono-service-device-registry.hono.svc.cluster.local/100.67.196.156:5671
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - connection attempt failed
io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException: Connection refused: hono-service-device-registry.hono.svc.cluster.local/100.67.196.156:5671
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:779)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doFinishConnect(NioSocketChannel.java:327)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe.finishConnect(AbstractNioChannel.java:336)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:685)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:632)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:549)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:511)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - starting attempt [#5005] to connect to server [hono-service-device-registry:5671]
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - OpenSSL [available: false, supports KeyManagerFactory: false, supports Hostname validation: false]
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - using JDK's default SSL engine
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - enabling secure protocol [TLSv1.2]
13:43:45.184 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqps://hono-service-device-registry:5671]
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - can't connect to AMQP 1.0 container [amqps://hono-service-device-registry:5671]: connection attempt timed out after 5000ms
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - connection attempt failed
org.eclipse.hono.connection.ConnectTimeoutException: connection attempt timed out after 5000ms
        at org.eclipse.hono.connection.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl.lambda$connect$0(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:140)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:911)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.handle(VertxImpl.java:875)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeTask(ContextImpl.java:320)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.EventLoopContext.execute(EventLoopContext.java:43)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:188)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.ContextImpl.executeFromIO(ContextImpl.java:180)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl$InternalTimerHandler.run(VertxImpl.java:901)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.client.impl.HonoConnectionImpl - starting attempt [#5170] to connect to server [hono-service-device-registry:5671]
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - OpenSSL [available: false, supports KeyManagerFactory: false, supports Hostname validation: false]
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - using JDK's default SSL engine
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - enabling secure protocol [TLSv1.2]
13:43:45.207 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - connecting to AMQP 1.0 container [amqps://hono-service-device-registry:5671]
13:43:45.208 [vert.x-eventloop-thread-0] DEBUG o.e.h.c.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl - ignoring failed connection attempt to AMQP 1.0 container [amqps://hono-service-device-registry:5671]: attempt already timed out
io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException: connection timed out: hono-service-device-registry.hono.svc.cluster.local/100.67.196.156:5671
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioChannel$AbstractNioUnsafe$1.run(AbstractNioChannel.java:263)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask$RunnableAdapter.call(PromiseTask.java:38)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:127)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:416)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:515)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:918)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
```

No endpoints for some pods:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# Kubectl get ep -n hono

NAME---ENDPOINTS
endpoints/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx
endpoints/hono-adapter-amqp-vertx-headless
endpoints/hono-adapter-http-vertx
endpoints/hono-adapter-http-vertx-headless
endpoints/hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx
endpoints/hono-adapter-mqtt-vertx-headless
endpoints/hono-artemis---100.96.1.6:5671
endpoints/hono-dispatch-router---100.96.2.5:5673
endpoints/hono-dispatch-router-ext---100.96.2.5:5671,100.96.2.5:5672
endpoints/hono-grafana---100.96.1.5:3000
endpoints/hono-prometheus-server---none
endpoints/hono-service-auth---100.96.2.7:5671
endpoints/hono-service-auth-headless---100.96.2.7
endpoints/hono-service-device-connection-headless---none
endpoints/hono-service-device-registry---none
endpoints/hono-service-device-registry-ext---none
endpoints/hono-service-device-registry-headless---none
```

No endpoint for the AMQP adaptor service too:

```
root@ip-172-31-35-125:~# kubectl -n hono describe service hono-adapter-amqp-vertx

Name:                     hono-adapter-amqp-vertx
Namespace:                hono
Labels:                   app.kubernetes.io/component=adapter-amqp-vertx
                          app.kubernetes.io/instance=hono
                          app.kubernetes.io/managed-by=Tiller
                          app.kubernetes.io/name=eclipse-hono
                          app.kubernetes.io/version=1.0-M7
                          helm.sh/chart=eclipse-hono-1.0-M7
Annotations:              kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:
                            {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"app.kubernetes.io/component":"adapter-amqp-vertx","app.kuberne...
Selector:                 app.kubernetes.io/component=adapter-amqp-vertx,app.kubernetes.io/instance=hono,app.kubernetes.io/name=eclipse-hono
Type:                     LoadBalancer
IP:                       100.67.94.188
LoadBalancer Ingress:     a25d01250eb3611e9b45f0e90af72a72-2016210601.eu-west-3.elb.amazonaws.com
Port:                     amqp  5672/TCP
TargetPort:               amqp/TCP
NodePort:                 amqp  32672/TCP
Endpoints:
Port:                     amqps  5671/TCP
TargetPort:               amqps/TCP
NodePort:                 amqps  32671/TCP
Endpoints:
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

I am not sure whether the problem is with my AWS k8s and VPC connectivity or with the Hono deployment? Any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: I assume the last listing is from the log of a protocol adapter. Right? Protocol adapters need to connect to the device registry. The listing of pods does not include a pod for the device registry. Can you check if you have deployed one?

Comment: The log is for amqp adaptor. You are right, there is no hono-service-device-registry! It is strange that the hono-service-device-registry-ext service is there and got an internal IP. I deployed the Hono services using Kubectl for Hono 1.0-M7 from here https://www.eclipse.org/hono/docs/deployment/helm-based-deployment/. Should I deploy the service registry separately?

Comment: When I get the ConfigMaps for Hono, it just shows the config for Grafana. Would it be the reason for that the HTTP probe failed? should I create ConfigMaps for different pods?

Comment: Please provide more readable and descriptive logs outputs like: `kubectl get pods,svc,ep -n hono, kubectl describe failed_pod -n hono`.
It looks like there is problem with connectivity or with "Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 503"  maybe it should be enough to exceed readiness timeout period: `delay=10s timeout=1s period=10s #success=1 #failure=3`

Comment: Thanks @Hanx , I made the logs more readable and provide the log for amqp protocol (a failed pod). It shows that there is no endpoint for some of pods. But when describe those failed pods (e.g.,AMQP), there is IP addresses (100.96.1.8). Any idea?

Comment: As I saw before last edit (connection was refused) as I can see now `hono-service-device-registry` service doesn't have ep. Those files doesn't help it difficult to read. My advice is - 1. provide clear logs, 2. run separate container within the same namespace and test connection to your endpoints,pods via services like `hono-service-device-registry`